# Migration magento 1 to magento 2

Tags: migration, magento2.2

Which is the best tool available for migration magento 1 to magento 2.

Can anyone give official magento tool for migration.

Comment: Try this one: [https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/). It's the best Magento migration tool I have used.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **official data migration tool** here that can help with the migration of the data side of things:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

**Themes** will however need to be recreated to work with the new Magento 2 store.

Further general information about migration is also here:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually Magento just provides us with the [Magento Data Migration Tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html) and [Magento Code Migration Toolkit](https://github.com/magento/code-migration).

Please check the following useful guides to know how to use these tools and migrate data, theme and extensions from Magento 1 to Magento 2:
[Magento 2 Data Migration Guide](https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-data-migration/), 
[Magento 2 Extension Migration Guide](https://dev.to/tigren5/how-to-migrate-extension-from-magento-1-to-2-2n1), 
[Magento 2 Theme Migration Guide](https://www.tigren.com/migrate-theme-magento-1-to-2/)